# Creating pointer to a typedef stack

Tags: c

I am not able to initialize all three pointers to *struct S*, and I don't know why.

I am using a fixed-length array as stack to store values.
The header file is created this way to hide information (*struct S*), and should be kept as generic as possible.

**main.c**

```
// main.c


#include <stdio.h>
#include "stack_exercise4.h"

int main(void) {
    Stack *stack_1, *stack_2, *stack_3;
    int a, b;

    make_empty(stack_1);
    make_empty(stack_2);
    make_empty(stack_3);

    return 0;
}
```

Problem is, after `Stack *stack_1, *stack_2, *stack_3`, only `stack_2` has a valid address for *Struct stack*. *stack_1* and *stack_3* have some strange looking addresses, and I can't assign any values to *stack_1->top*, nor *stack_3->top*.  What is the problem?

[image]

**header file**

```
// stack_exercise4.h

#ifndef STACK_EXERCISE4_H
#define STACK_EXERCISE4_H

#include <stdbool.h>   /* C99 only */

typedef struct S Stack; /* incomplete type to hide the content
                           of S. */

void make_empty(Stack *s);
bool is_empty(const Stack *s);
bool is_full(const Stack *s);
void push(Stack *s, int i);
int pop(Stack *s);

#endif
```

**stack source file**

```
// stack_exercise4a.c

#include "stack_exercise4.h"
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_STACK_SIZE (10)

struct S {
    int top;
    int contents[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
};

void make_empty(Stack *s) {
    s->top = 0;
}

bool is_empty(const Stack *s) {
    return (s->top <= 0);
}

bool is_full(const Stack *s) {
    return (s->top >= MAX_STACK_SIZE - 1);
}

void push(Stack *s, int i) {
    if (!is_full(s)){
        (s->contents)[s->top++] = i;        
    } else {
        printf("Failed to push, Stack is full.\n");
    }
}

int pop(Stack *s) {
    return (s->contents)[s->top--];
}
```

Comment: Your stack pointers are left uninitialized

Comment: Generally, extract a [mcve] from your code first. For example, you would not have written about three pointers, when one is already enough. Also, I believe that some compilers could have given you warnings about your code, if you have warnings enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack pointers must point on memory spaces before being dereferenced in *make_empty()*. Something like this could be the starting point: *make_empty()* allocates the memory space.

```c
void make_empty(Stack **s) {
  (*s) = (struct S *)malloc(sizeof(struct S));
  (*s)->top = 0;
}
```

And so the initialization of the pointers would be:

```c
    make_empty(&stack_1);
    make_empty(&stack_2);
    make_empty(&stack_3);
```

Answer (score -1):

Declare `stack_X` on stack instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stack_exercise4.h"

int main(void) {
    Stack stack_1 = {0}, stack_2 = {0}, stack_3 = {0};
    int a, b;

    make_empty(&stack_1);
    make_empty(&stack_2);
    make_empty(&stack_3);

    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, I't would need to have constructor/destructor for your `Stack` data structure e.g `new_stack(Stack *ptr)` `del_stack(Stack *ptr)`. For beginner, I would recommend to use stack instead of heap (stay away from `malloc`).

Comment: The stack has a limited size in some systems. And anyway, stacks are not destined to long-term allocations. And it is error prone : imagine you are getting out of the function which allocated the data structure in the stack : the data become invalid. The dynamic allocation like malloc() or new() which hides a low level malloc() are advised.

Comment: Same thing happened with dynamic allocation, malloc-without-free, use-after-free, out-of-memory, etc. For kind of exercite like this, use stack helps reduce complexity and bugs. BTW: for small system there is no c-std lib -> malloc will not be resented, for realtime application(for RTOS), malloc will be banned. If you run-out of stack, compiler will warning.

Comment: In small RTOS, if there are no dynamic allocator, it is preferable to use static global allocations. The stack ones are rarely the solution. Concerning malloc(), the free can be forgotten causing a memory leak but at least the memory does not disappear implicitely when you go out of the function which allocated the data. And if you run out of heap, you are also warned : malloc() return NULL. It is not always possible for the compiler to detect stacks overflows. It is detected a run time with a red zone on the top of the stack which triggers an exception when touched.

Comment: The run-time stack overflow detection needs extra code or a memory management unit implementing R/W access protection on memory areas. This is not always available on small RTOS systems.

Comment: Considering that if the data not valid after exiting from specific scope, this kind of errors are easy to detect at development phase, but memory leak takes days, months to be able to detected(requires longrun tests, stress tests, heatrun tests).